# Newbie: how to restore nuget packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, nuget

I've downloaded a C# project, based on NuGet packages, but I fail to restore them. Here you see what happens when I ask for restoring those packages: (in top of this, the "Autenticator" app on my smartphone constantly asks me for permission (which I'm giving, of course).

Hereby the results of a `NuGet restore` in commandline (just for one particular package, there are lots of them:

```
C:\<Project_Dir>>nuget restore
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.10.2.30804' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
Restoring NuGet package Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961.
...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/Own_Product.client.core/1.52.1961/Own_Product.client.core.1.52.1961.nupkg
...
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/Own_Product.client.core/1.52.1961/Own_Product.client.core.1.52.1961.nupkg 459ms
...
  GET https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2/Packages(Id='Own_Product.Client.Core',Version='1.52.1961')
...
  NotFound https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2/Packages(Id='Own_Product.Client.Core',Version='1.52.1961') 1252ms
  GET https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Own_Product.Client.Core'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
...
  OK https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Own_Product.Client.Core'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 422ms
...
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.52.1961' of package 'Own_Product.Client.Core'.
  C:\Users\this_User\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'C:\Users\this_User\.nuget\packages\'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
  https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2'.
...
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.52.1961' of package 'Own_Product.Client.Core'.
  C:\Users\this_User\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'C:\Users\this_User\.nuget\packages\'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
  https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2: Package 'Own_Product.Client.Core.1.52.1961' is not found on source 'https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Own_ProductNuGetFeed/nuget/v2'.
...
```

For your information:

1. I'm using NuGet.exe version 5.9.1.11, instead of the standard 2.8.50126.400 one.
2. The result of `Nuget list Own_Product.client.core` gives another version than the one I'm seem to be looking for while doing the regular compilation:

   ```
    C:\<Project_Dir>>nuget list Own_Product.client.core
    nuget list Own_Product.client.core
    MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.10.2.30804' from 
      'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
    Own_Product.Client.Core 20.3.18.1
   ```

Comment: What C# project did you download? What server do you expect to find Own_Product.Client.Core on?

Comment: @canton7: maybe my question is unclear: the project I've downloaded and the NuGet package I'm trying to restore, are products from my employer, it's not something I downloaded from the internet, if that is what you mean.

Comment: OK, and what server does your employer store their NuGet packages such as Own_Product.Client.Core on? Maybe you should ask someone in your office for help, since this problem is about this project apparently not being configured to fetch packages from the right place, or the packages not being available where they should be available. Since this is all private, I don't think we can help with either!

Comment: @canton7: I'm sorry, but where can I find that information? (I'm looking into "*.sln", "*.csproj" files, NuGet.Targets, NuGet.config, I don't know where to find that information.

Comment: @canton7: all my colleagues have a system, which is working fine. I'm the only one, having the issue, hence my question.

Comment: You ask someone who knows how things work. The project is configured to fetch packages from https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com, but can't find them. It's unclear whether this is because https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com is wrong, or because that version of the package was removed from https://Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com. You'll have to ask someone who knows what's going on.

Comment: Every half-decent project will have some sort of onboarding document which tells you how to set things up to build the project. Ask someone for it, and if it's incomplete, ask them how to fix it and ensure someone updates the doc (or do it yourself)

Comment: Canton7 and JonasH’s suggestions are helpful. You need to make sure that the URL to your package source has set well, in VS > Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources. Also, make sure that the specific version of the NuGet package existed and available to get. And communicate with other colleagues to see if you did something or configured something different from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention that this is for an internal repository it is likely that you are missing the package source for your internal repo. This is specified in the %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config file, and is easiest to edit thru the [visual studio package sources dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)

Looking at the error it seems like nuget is looking for the package at `api.nuget.org` and `Own_Product.pkgs.visualstudio.com`. The later does not seem look like a real repository for visual studio, so it might be miss-configured.

Since it is an internal repo it is difficult say what the exact settings should be, I would suggest you ask a college to send a copy of the settings they use.